# URL doesn't reload if sites go offline

Tags: support, offline

Site went offline. After that I was trying to reload the page but it kept on showing me that the site is offline.

Here is the link that I was using and it's still showing me that the site is offline, but right now site is alive.

http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/app_offline.htm?return=http%3A//stackoverflow.com/users/179855/piemesons%23qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_recent-ansort_votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click the link indicated by the arrow, please.

   [image: retry your request]
2. The **page automatically tries to contact the server and will attempt to refresh to the destination URL every 5 minutes** (assuming you have JavaScript enabled).